# Why is this simple javascript code not working?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
var interval = 250
setInterval(function(){
if ( 1==1 ) {
interval = 5000
}
}, interval)
```

This should set interval at 5000 if 1 == 1 but it keeps the interval at 250.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `interval` in this case is evaluated just once, when `setInterval` function is called (note the difference with `setInterval` *parameter* function, which will be called repeatedly).

To make the interval change after the first run, you can use `setTimeout` instead, with something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  (function _t() {
    // doSomethingUseful(); 
    setTimeout(_t, 5000);
  })();
}, 250);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the interval without calling setInterval all over again. I would use some sort of setTimeout loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

When the callback function is executed, setInterval was called using 250 as parameter, and when you change interval value in the function, this change doesn't affect the previously set value.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval will call the callback every 250 MS, , but setInterval itself will be called once